# phonegap with server rendered html form produces null referrer error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, cordova, phonegap, w3c

I have a basic phonegap app with just default index.html, once the index.html is loaded and device_ready event fires, i load the html form
straight from the server using ajax and replace just the body of the index.html.
So far so good..
but when in submit the form back to rails server, i get following error

```
ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken (The browser returned a 'null' origin for a request with origin-based forgery protection turned on. This usually
means you have the 'no-referrer' Referrer-Policy header enabled, or that you the request came from a site that
refused to give its origin. This makes it impossible for Rails to verify the source of the requests. Likely the
best solution is to change your referrer policy to something less strict like same-origin or strict-same-origin.
If you cannot change the referrer policy, you can disable origin checking with the
Rails.application.config.action_controller.forgery_protection_origin_check setting.
):
```

i have tried setting referrer in the index.html as

```
    <meta name="referrer" content="unsafe-url" /> or
    <meta name="referrer" content="origin-when-crossorigin" />
```

produces

```
HTTP Origin header (file://) didn't match request.base_url (http://192.168.1.5:4000)
```

still getting the same error.

Some additional info:
index.html protocol is file:///
server_side.html with http:// protocol is XHR loaded into index.html

Answer (score 0):

I know it's too late for answering this question and you probably solved it.

Anyway, I solved a similar issue, for my particular purpose, by adding the following line to `config/application.rb` in my Rails app:

```
Rails.application.config.action_controller.forgery_protection_origin_check = false
```